# Watchkit - How to set the element one below other in Group

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I am working on the watchkit app and I want to create a table row with an image and two labels where the labels are one below the other, like this:

[image]

I tried the position options in interface builder, but no luck.

[image]

The labels are always on the same line:

[image]

I want the x-coordinate same for both.
Please help.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to accomplish; are you trying to make a tableViewCell with 2 labels that are stacked one on top of the other? So, in your picture, label 2 would be directly below label 1, both with the same x position?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

At first, drag a `Group` onto the interfaceController, then change the `Layout` property of that group to `Vertical`:

[image]

Then drag the Labels in that group and set their properties accordingly:

[image]

If you need other alignments, add another group to the viewController.

---

**EDIT**

To achieve the table view you have posted in your question:

1. put a group on the table row, set its layout to `Horizontal`
2. put the image in that group, position `Left`
3. put another group in that group, position `Left`, layout `Vertical`
4. put the labels in that second group

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: well this is table actually only one group per row is allowed.

Comment: Is there a way to get the titlelabel and datalabel closer together?

Comment: Perfect adding more groups ! you saved my day.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to change `Layout` of that group to `Vertical`

Comment: but i also have one label in between middle like one in middle which is leftside and other 2 are one above at right side

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you're trying to accomplish, could you draw how you want to position your labels?